# Как проверить, целое ли число типа double

Tags: java

[image]

**Задача**
Обработайте некорректные данные (ничего не ввёл, отрицательные число, 0, нецелое число), выведя соответствующие уведомления.

Я сделал всё, кроме "нецелого числа". Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе нецелого числа программа выдавала сообщение?

Comment: `if(str.contains(".") || str.contains(","))`

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(string_to_check);` если не целое - вот вам и исключение. (если вводится строка с числом, а потом её нужно проверить)

Comment: Я прикрепил картинку кода, можете пожалуйста посмотреть!

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Первый способ:

```java
if (str.contains(".") || str.contains(",")) {
    ...
}
```

---

Второй способ:

```java
try {
    Integer.parseInt(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    ...
}
```

---

Третий способ:

```java
if (n % 1 != 0) {
    ...
}
```

---

Четвёртый способ:

```java
if ((int)n != n) {
    ...
}
```

---

Первый способ не работает с числами в экспоненциальной записи, содержащими точку (или запятую), такими как `1.1E1`, что равно 11.
Второй способ помимо этого не работает вообще ни с какими числами, представленными в экспоненциальной записи.

Все вышеперечисленные способы не работают с +-`Infinity` и `NaN`. Если такие "числа" могут возникнуть при вводе, на них следует проверить заранее.

Comment: Первый способ не обнаружит числа в экспоненциальной записи.

Comment: @КириллМалышев как раз таки обнаружит, но может ошибиться, так как число в такой записи может быть целым даже с точкой. Кстати, второй способ тоже этого не обнаружит.

Comment: поддерживаю третий вариант)